# Integrating spherical harmonics

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to simply check the integration/normalization condition on the SperhicalHarmonic functions that are built into Mathematica. So basically, I just want to check that the following integral

```
Integrate[Conjugate[SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, ϑ, φ]]  SphericalHarmonicY[l', m', ϑ, φ] Sin[ϑ], {φ, 
0, 2 π}, {ϑ, 0, π}]
```

evalutes to delta_{l,l'}delta_{m,m'}

But the evaluation just gives me:

```
\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(∫\), \(0\), \(2\ π\)]\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(∫\), \(0\), \(π\)]\(Conjugate[
 SphericalHarmonicY[l, 
  m, ϑ, φ]]\ Sin[ϑ]\ \
SphericalHarmonicY[\*
SuperscriptBox["l", "′",
MultilineFunction->None], \*
SuperscriptBox["m", "′",
MultilineFunction->None], ϑ, φ]\) \
\[DifferentialD]ϑ \[DifferentialD]φ\)\)
```

For anyone having trouble reading that mess (sorry!), the evaluation doesn't do anything. It just returns the expression for the double integral, ***unevaluated***

If anyone has any advice it would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Your problem might be that you used the confusing symbols *l'* and *m'*, which *Mathematica* interprets as derivatives.  If you use instead *ll* and *mm* and restrict them to integer values, perhaps it will work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a general rule, avoid using *l'* and *m'*, which *Mathematica* interprets as derivatives.

*Mathematica* has difficulty performing the integration for symbolic constants *l*, *m*, *ll* and *mm*, but can verify orthonormality for a finite range of those values:

```
    Table[Assuming[{l, ll, m, mm} \[Element] Integers, 
   Integrate[
    Conjugate[
      SphericalHarmonicY[l, 
       m, \[CurlyTheta], \[CurlyPhi]]] SphericalHarmonicY[ll, 
      mm, \[CurlyTheta], \[CurlyPhi]] Sin[\[CurlyTheta]], {\
\[CurlyTheta], 0, \[Pi]}, {\[CurlyPhi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}]], {l, 1, 3}, {ll,
    1, 3}, {m, -l, l}, {mm, -ll, ll}] // MatrixForm
```

$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$

Comment: Usually people only care about `m` values between `-l` and `+l`, so the table won't be square. But your main point is that we need to be explicit about the indices, and I think there's no better  way of getting results (+1).