# Confirming orthogonality of spherical harmonics symbolically

Tags: special-functions

One can confirm the orthogonality of the `SphericalHarmonicY`s for specific values of their parameters (`l, m, ll, mm`) as I showed in my solution [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75289/integrating-spherical-harmonics), but I have been unable to verify it for the *general* case, as in:

```
Assuming[{l, ll, m, mm} ∈ Integers && 
   -l <= m <= l && -ll <= mm <= ll , 
 Integrate[
  Conjugate[
    SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, ϑ, φ]] 
    SphericalHarmonicY[ll, mm, ϑ, φ] 
    Sin[ϑ],
  {ϑ, 0, π}, {φ, 0, 2 π}]]
```

Are there any tricks, or assumptions, or other techniques that enable *Mathematica* to symbolically evaluate that integral (leading to a product of `KroneckerDelta` functions)?  I even tried `FunctionExpand` to express each `SphericalHarmonicY` using exponentials and other simpler functions, but the integral was still not evaluated.

Comment: You probably mean [Kronecker deltas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta), not [Dirac deltas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

Comment: The $\phi$ integral is easy, as $Y_{\ell}^m(\theta ,\phi)=\sqrt{\frac{2\ell+1}{4\pi}\frac{(\ell-m)!}{(\ell+m)!}}P_{\ell}^m(\cos \theta)e^{i m\phi}$. The difficult part is to show that the Legendre polynomials are orthogonal. This may simplify your question to showing in an abstract way that [standard orthogonal polynomials](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrthogonalPolynomials.html) are indeed orthogonal.

Comment: I think you can do the conjugation symbolically by replacing `φ -> -φ`

Comment: @mikado:  Yes.  You can even perform the symbolic integration over $\phi$, which accomplishes the same thing.  The remaining difficulty seems to be the $\theta$ integral, which is resisting all my creative attempts!

Comment: I don't think the game is  worth the candle. Of course, these integrals can be implemented as table values.

Comment: @user64494:  Well, The broader issue is how to expand computer algebra systems (of which *Mathematica* is best), to cope with a broader and broader range of important mathematical problems.  We can dismiss this particular "one-off" and say "it's been solved... look it up," but there are innumerable other important integrals (including with lots of special functions) where it would be great to have automated answers.  Moreover, once we solve these normalizations (analytically) it will likely lead to solutions to related integrals, such as with three spherical harmonics, or two with a polynomial

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: See S. Axler, P. Bourdon, and W. Ramey, Harmonic function theory pp. 75-76 concerning the orthogonality under consideration. The authors do not calculate the integrals, but make a trick with the Green's formula. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: @user64494:  I think it is on the linked pdf https://www.axler.net/HFT.pdf.  I studied all this when I was getting my PhD in Physics and have taught it.  But I guess I don't quite see the relevance.  I *know* the orthogonality relations of the spherical harmonics, and (long ago) derived them myself by hand.  My question *on this site* is how to perform the integrals symbolically using *Mathematica*?  For example, can one impose the Green's function "trick" through some forced substitution or condition?  Must we simply accept that *Mathematica* currently is of little or no use?

Comment: @user64494:  Oh... and the Green's function trick shows us only orthogonality... not ortho *normality* (i.e., that certain integrals yield 1.0).

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer but an extended comment.

This may be difficult. Let's look at the $\phi$ dependence, which for $\mu=m-m'$ can be reduced to the integral
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i \mu \phi}d\phi = 2\pi\delta_{\mu,0}
$$
for $\mu\in\mathbb{Z}$. In Mathematica, even this simplified case does not work:

```
Assuming[Element[μ, Integers], 
  Integrate[Exp[I*μ*φ], {φ, 0, 2π}]]
(*    0    *)
```

We see that Mathematica only gives the general case $\mu\neq0$ and overlooks the special case $\mu=0$. Mathematica often gives [generic solutions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ManipulatingEquationsAndInequalities.html#1205) and skips over non-generic ones.

With this in mind, I think that showing polynome orthogonality or even orthonormality will be difficult, and tricks are needed that I'm not familiar with.

Comment: Thanks.  (+1). I too found exactly this example and it led me to your general conclusion that *Mathematica*, in "default" mode, could not solve even these "simple" integrals.  But I'm trying to collect heuristics and hacks that can expand *Mathematica*'s symbolic capability and hoped that there might be one for this orthogonality problem.  Example hack:  *Mathematica* fails at some multi-variable integrals in default mode, but succeeds when you perform the individual (single-variable) component integrals individually.  Perhaps I'll post a "bigger" question to this effect as a service.